# Disable volume control Win 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, group-policy, regedit

I work at a hospital and one of the nurse managers over a department is wanting the volume set to a specific level and to prevent users from adjusting it. It's a Windows 10 computer. Is there a way to accomplish this with group policy, reg edit?

Answer (score 3):

To remove the Sound Volume icon from the taskbar :

- Right-click the taskbar and select "Taskbar Settings"
- Under "Notification area" click "Select which icons appear on the taskbar"
- Turn Off the toggle for "Volume"
- The effect should be immediate.

If the computer's keyboard has built-in multi-media keys for
setting the volume, you would need to install
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
for blocking them.
Let me know if you need this.

Answer (score 3):

A very handy system-wide utility called [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/) should be able to limit your volume output.

- Once installed, open the 'Configuration Editor' and from the File menu open the '**config.txt**' file. The path should be:
  `C:\Program Files\EqualizerAPO\config` (or wherever you installed the program). It should find this directory automatically. Opening the **config.txt** file will launch the GUI where you can add control parameters for your system.
- Choose which system sound device you wish to control in the top section of the GUI:
  [image]
- Click the green plus sign on the left side to add a new control parameter. Click on 'Basic Filters', then 'Preamp'.

[image]

- Next adjust the 'Gain' dial to your preferred liking. In your case you will be turning the dial left to attenuate the volume.
- Lastly, save the file and restart your system to test if the adjustments have taken effect.

You can also try out some of the other parameters to help adjust the volume. There is one called "Loudness Correction":

[image]

Full documentation of all the features of EqualizerAPO can be found [HERE](https://sourceforge.net/p/equalizerapo/wiki/Documentation/).

Comment: How does this lock the volume level?

Comment: @pipe by adding a filter that attenuates volume. Setting it to very low would create a ceiling.

Comment: No one mentioned a ceiling.

Comment: @pipe You are right! I assumed that the nurse who requested this wanted the level to not exceed a certain volume, but it could very well be that she wants the opposite. If that is the case I will edit my answer.